# jquery slider has mystery margin in ie 6/7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slider, coda-slider

First view the page I am having problems with here: 
http://3hqidiots.com/onthespot/calendar.html

I am using the slider found here: http://ennuidesign.com/demo/contentslider/ to slide different calendars. It loads perfectly in all browsers but ie 6/7. In ie 6/7, the first calendar loads with a left margin. Then you slide to the next calendar and it loads perfectly. Then you slide back to the first calendar and it loads perfectly. It is how the javascript is substantiating the calender within the slider, but I can't figure out what it is.

The strange part is that the slider works perfectly in ie6/7 with the demo files, as does the calendar....but together they dont want to position themselves correctly in ie 6/7. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that both the body and the calendar container selectors had css rules of: text-align: center. I removed that and everything worked perfectly!